# Javascript Redirect - Wrong redirect

Tags: javascript, jquery, redirect

I use the javascript redirect function, to redirect whenever a form has completed the processing.

It use it like this:

```
redirect("?i=login"); //On the page. http://www.domain.com/folder/?i=index
```

Although, it redirects to: http://www.domain.com/folder/www.domain.com/folder/?i=login

Why is that?

Comment: well probably the way your redirect function has been set up, maybe you should use, `redirect('/?i=login')` or the full url, or if you want it to rewrite it let us know.

Comment: Is the redirect function made by you or does it come from a library?

Comment: Take a look at this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/503093/how-can-i-make-a-redirect-page-in-jquery

Comment: If you ask what's wrong with a custom function and you don't post the function code, what kind of answers do you expect?

Answer (score 2):

Use `window.location.assign('?i=login');`